# Errors on a zpool filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, raid, zfs, zpool

I'm using ZFS on a Debian 9 machine.
This machine has been working for years without any problem until today.

The zfs pool is mounted on top of a RAID system, controlled by hardware (so only one drive is exposed to Linux as sda). You can see the output of "zpool status" below.

Before continuing, just mention that I checked the consistency of the RAID, and everything is fine.

Suddenly, all accesses to the filesystem provoke the command to freeze (even an ls command), and eventually, I need to reboot the machine manually.

When running `zpool status -v`, the output is:

```
#/sbin/zpool status -v
  pool: export
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 53h4m with 0 errors on Tue Mar 15 05:28:38 2022
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        export      ONLINE       0     0     0
          sda       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        export/home:<0x0>
        export/home:<0x2b2ed23>
        export/home:<0x2e1183b>
        export/home:<0x2b2e849>
        export/home:<0x1d0b5b1>
```

So, the main question is: What is the meaning of those files? How do I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did the scrubs work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a `zpool clear` and two scrubs if you can, then see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Those *was* corrupted files and now remains metadata:

```
export/home:<0x0>
export/home:<0x2b2ed23>
export/home:<0x2e1183b>
export/home:<0x2b2e849>
export/home:<0x1d0b5b1>
```

The cause is probably a hardware failure, but you need more information to point the root cause and you will probably be stopped by your RAID card.

Using a RAID hardware device under ZFS [**is not recommended**](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Performance%20and%20Tuning/Hardware.html#hardware-raid-controllers) to avoid the exact situation you encounters: hard time to diagnose issues.

My two cents:

- let ZFS manage your disks (it is made for it)
- use the most recent ZFS version (and a adequat OS)

Comment: Hardware RAID controllers don't fall over at an excessive rate for other filesystems. It's misleading to state that they're unacceptable for ZFS, or that single-lun/single device pools backed by hardware RAID is unacceptable. I common use case is an export from a SAN, ZFS in a VM or any situation where one wants to leverage ZFS volume management features without using the RAID features.

Comment: OK then, so what are your suggestions to diagnose this case @ewwhite?

Comment: Oh, a `zpool clear` and two scrubs.